# Kivy - Show/hide Rectangle depending on result of If statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

I have an "email" text box that receives user input and then evaluates whether or not it's a valid email. I want to show a red rectangle around the text box if the email is invalid, and hide it if the opposite is true. I already have the rectangle drawn, now it's just a matter of toggling its visibility.

*user.py*

```
"""User-end software for signup/account data."""
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import re


class LoginScreen(Widget):
    """Class for signup screen contents."""

    email = StringProperty()
    password = StringProperty()

    def login(self):
        """Actions for when Login button is pressed."""
        if not re.fullmatch(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", self.email):  # Check if email is valid
            print("Invalid email!")  # Hide rectangle instead of this


class UserApp(App):
    """Main app."""

    def build(self):
        """Build app."""
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UserApp().run()
```

*user.kv*

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<LoginScreen>:
    email: email_input.text
    password: password_input.text
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:  # show/hide this object
            size:  root.width * 5 / 7 + 6, 46
            pos: root.width * 1 / 7 - 3, root.top - 259
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top + 20
        text: "Offbox Insurance"
    Label:
        font_size: 64
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 30
        text: "Log in"
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 140
        text: "Email"
    TextInput:
        id: email_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 216
        multiline: False
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 240
        text: "Password"
    TextInput:
        id: password_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 316
        multiline: False
        password: True
    Button:
        font_size: 20
        height: 50
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 380
        text: "Log in"
        on_press: root.login()
    Label:
        font_size: 16
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 75
        text: "Don't have an account?"
    Button:
        font_size: 16
        height: 36
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 5
        text: "Sign up"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So. This is they way I would do it and here is a working example. I would keep the rectangle black when you load it up then make it turn red if invalid. So I put the canvas within a widget so I could assign it an id and also set valid_color to the code for black then set rgba to valid(color). Inside of the login function I changed the value of valid color if it is invalid and just left it at black if it is valid or change it back to black if it was previously invalid. Here is the code:

user.py:

```
"""User-end software for signup/account data."""
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import re


class LoginScreen(Widget):
    """Class for signup screen contents."""

    email = StringProperty()
    password = StringProperty()

    def login(self):
        """Actions for when Login button is pressed."""
        if not re.fullmatch(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", self.email):  # Check if email is valid
            print("Invalid email!")  # Hide rectangle instead of this
            self.ids.valid_login.valid_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
        else:
            print('Valid Email!')
            self.ids.valid_login.valid_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)



class UserApp(App):
    """Main app."""

    def build(self):
        """Build app."""
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UserApp().run()
```

user.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<LoginScreen>:
    email: email_input.text
    password: password_input.text
    Widget:
        id: valid_login
        valid_color:(0, 0, 0, 0)
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: self.valid_color
            Rectangle:
                size:  root.width * 5 / 7 + 6, 46
                pos: root.width * 1 / 7 - 3, root.top - 259
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top + 20
        text: "Offbox Insurance"
    Label:
        font_size: 64
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 30
        text: "Log in"
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 140
        text: "Email"
    TextInput:
        id: email_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 216
        multiline: False
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 240
        text: "Password"
    TextInput:
        id: password_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 316
        multiline: False
        password: True
    Button:
        font_size: 20
        height: 50
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 380
        text: "Log in"
        on_press:
            root.login()
    Label:
        font_size: 16
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 75
        text: "Don't have an account?"
    Button:
        font_size: 16
        height: 36
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 5
        text: "Sign up"
```

I also recommend, if you plan on making multiple pages, to go ahead and implement Screen Manager but what I have given solves the validation problem. Hope this helps!